# Clean up time: Put away your toys

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, vocabulary

I am looking for very clear written instructions for a 7-year-old person or anyone who can read. The instructions are about putting away legos and throwing away trash bits left on the floor. I am looking for step-by-step instructions that are also natural and common. Below are what I've come up with.

Putting away legos:

> First, gather up the lego blocks into a pile in front of you using
>   both hands. Next, cup the palms of your hands and while keeping them
>   on the floor, draw them together simultaneously picking the blocks off
>   the floor. Then, carry the blocks over to the box and drop them
>   inside.

Throwing away trash:

> Sweep all the trash bits with (the edges of) your palms and make a
>   small pile. Next, grab them off the floor, holding them in your fists.
>   Lastly, throw them into the bin.

I know these are not the most common sets of instructions. Please, give feedback. Are there any commonly used vocabulary verbs for such specific actions?

Comment: That's all fine except where you use "picking" it would be more common to say "scoop up" which would imply using your palms. Picking is done with fingers.

Comment: It's pretty good, except that "trash bits" sounds weird and non-idiomatic.  Why not just "trash", which is already a noun?  Also, if you say "grab them off the floor", why follow it with "holding them in your fists"?  If you grabbed them, you're already holding them.